# How to use numpy.dstack in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to populate an array by using 2D arrays with np.dstack.

```
m1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
m2 = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
m3 = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])

lst = m1
lst = np.dstack((lst,m2))
lst = np.dstack((lst,m3))
```

What's the proper way to do it in a loop? I'm looking for something like

```
lst = np.empty(...)
for _
    lst = np.dstack((lst,variable2Darray))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the docs state: *This function continues to be supported for backward compatibility, but you should prefer np.concatenate or np.stack*. You can get the equivalent with `np.stack((m1,m2,m3), axis=2)`

Comment: I need something recursive, the variables are not present at same time

Comment: Do you want a possible way or the proper way?  Doing it once after collecting everything in a list is the best way.

Comment: Is there any python equivalent for following matlab code:                       i=1:10
    var = some2Dmatrix
    A(:,:,i) = var;
end --- I think I need a function like append to populate a 3D np.array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have shown, you can put the arrays in a list, and join them into a new array with one call:

```
In [173]: m1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
     ...: m2 = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
     ...: m3 = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [174]: alist = [m1,m2,m3]
In [175]: np.stack(alist)
Out[175]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [3, 3]]])
```

In numpy the first axis is the outer most.  In contrast in MATLAB the last axis is outermost.  So `stack` (or `np.array(alist)`) is the natural equivalent.  But if you must join them on a new inner axis use:

```
In [176]: np.stack(alist,axis=2)        # or np.dstack(alist)
Out[176]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Or if you are creating the arrays one at a time, use a list append:

```
In [177]: alist = []
In [178]: for a in m1,m2,m3:
     ...:     alist.append(a)
```

Perhaps the closest thing to your MATLAB is:

```
In [181]: arr = np.zeros((2,2,3),int)
In [183]: for i,m in enumerate([m1,m2,m3]):
     ...:     arr[:,:,i] = m

for i=1:10 
    var = some2Dmatrix 
    A(:,:,i) = var;
end
```

In contrast to MATLAB `numpy` does not simply add a layer when you index beyond the current size.  I also suspect that MATLAB code actually hides some costly matrix resizing code.  It's not something I did years ago when I used MATLAB professionally.

But to answer the question that we don't want to answer:

```
In [185]: arr = np.zeros((2,2,0),int)   # your empty(?)
In [187]: for m in (m1,m2,m3):
     ...:     arr = np.concatenate((arr, m[:,:,None]), axis=2)    
In [188]: arr.shape
Out[188]: (2, 2, 3)
```

If you don't understand the details of this iteration, you probably shouldn't be trying to build a larger array with repeated `concatenate` (or `dstack`).  You have to get the initial shape of `arr` correct, and you have to get the right shape of the iteration array right.  Plus this is making brand new `arr` with each loop.  That's costlier than list append.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop. You need a list or a tuple of arrays:

```
m1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
m2 = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
m3 = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])

arrays = m1, m2, m3 # A tuple of arrays
lst = np.dstack(arrays) # Stack them all
```

Comment: I need dstack in the loop. I want to start with an empty lst, then populate

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this in a `for` loop, you can add a variable number of matrices in the tuple you pass to `np.dstack`, like:

```
>>> np.dstack((m1, m2, m3))
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar need recently. Although this answer is very late, it does show how to do this with a loop as you requested.

---

```
m1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
m2 = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
m3 = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])

alst = [m1,m2,m3]

lst = alst[0]
for i in range(1,len(alst)):
    lst = np.dstack((lst,alst[i]))
```