# How do I add an element to numpy nd array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I want to add a matrix of shape (60,4) to an empty numpy array of shape (1000,60,4)
However when i use the following code it fails

```
np.append(arr=array,values=i)
```

In the above code , the shape of object ***i*** is (60,4),
By **it fails** i mean it adds a matrix full of zeroes to the array which is not expected . Am I doing anything wrong
How can I add the matrix to the array keeping my final output as (1000,60,4)?

**NOTE**
Don't duplicate this question . It is different from questions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332841/add-single-element-to-array-in-numpy)
I have not a 1d array but a more complex nd array.
Thanks for help

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Normally when people use `np.append` and an 'empty` array, they are trying emulate the list `alist=[]; alist.append(some_value)` process.  I explored the problems with that in a recent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135673/how-to-use-numpy-dstack-in-a-loop.  You are using 'add' in a very different sense.  Your (1000,64,4) array is not 'empty'  in the sense that `[]` is empty.  It's already filled with values (0's or random ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your 60,4 to any of your 1000 positions.

```
big_array[pos] = little_array
```

example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3,6,4))
b = np.ones((6,4))

a[1] = b
```

yields:

```
           a[1]=  
           [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **assign** a value to one of the element of array, you have to use **assign** operation, not **concatenation**, what you made:

```
import numpy as np
np.append(arr=array,values=i)
```

will results in a list with the shape (**240240,**)

**Assigning** to one of the element of array:

```
   arr[0] = i
```

will results in a list with the shape (**1000,60,4**)