# Numpy: How to stack 3D arrays in rows iteratively?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to stack into rows (axis=0) the results of a calculation that results in 3D arrays. I don't know the results ahead of time.

```
import numpy as np

h = 10
w = 20
c = 30
result_4d = np.???   # empty

for i in range(5):
   result_3d = np.zeros((h, w, c))  #fake calculation
   result_4d = np.???  # stacked result_3ds on axis=0

return result_4d
```

I've tried various permutations of the numpy *stack calls but I inevitably run into shape mismatch errors.

Comment: Once you understand array shapes well, you'll be able define the correct "empty" starting point.  It's a good exercise in working with shape, but it isn't the fastest way.

Comment: For a more detailed answer, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135673/how-to-use-numpy-dstack-in-a-loop

Comment: The basic tool for joining arrays is `np.concatenate`.  That takes a list of n-d array, and joins them on a selected axis to make a new n-d array.  That means, to get a 4d array, you need to start with 4d arrays.  If you use the iterative approach the initial "empty" array must itself be 4d, but with 0 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a list first and then stack.

```
h = 10
w = 20
c = 30
l = []
for i in range(5):
    result_3d = np.zeros((h, w, c))  #fake calculation
    l.append(result_3d)
res = np.stack(l, axis=-1)

res.shape # (10, 20, 30, 5)

# move stacked axis around ...
np.transpose(res, (3,0,1,2)).shape # (5, 10, 20, 30)
```

If you want to update in loop, you can potentially do this:

```
res = ''
for i in range(5):
    result_3d = np.zeros((h, w, c))  #fake calculation
    if type(res) is str:
        res = np.array([result_3d]) # add dimension
        continue
    res = np.vstack((res, np.array([result_3d]))) # stack on that dimension

res.shape # (5, 10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of that but I was wondering if there was a direct solution without the intermediate variable.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude found a way to do that, you need to add a dimension so stack would work.

Comment: Thanks.  I've also changed the range to range(5) to disambiguate the shape.

Comment: Edited to reflect that change.

Comment: Stacking inside the loop instead of in one call after the loop is a really bad idea, since the amount of data copying is then proportional to the square of the loop length instead of directly proportional to the loop length. For `range(5)`, that may not matter too much, but then later when that 5 becomes 5 million, it can be catastrophic.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, do you know if there's a overwrite self numpy array function that would do something akin to `append` instead of creating new arrays?

Comment: `resize` is the only thing that changes an array's shape in-place and that has restrictions.  Repeat after me: 'an array is not a list'.  Its data storage is very different.